# How to find specific value element in array by specific attribut?

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter, find

```
var attributeList = [];

var attributeEmail = {
    Name : 'email',
    Value : 'email@mydomain.com'
};
var attributePhoneNumber = {
    Name : 'phone_number',
    Value : '+15555555555'
};
attributeList.push(attributeEmail);
attributeList.push(attributePhoneNumber);
```

result is:

```
Attributes: Array(2)
1: {Name: "phone_number", Value: "+15555555555"}
2: {Name: "email", Value: "email@mydomain.com"}
```

I need find email in `attributeList`

```
var email = getEmail(attributeList);
console.log(email); // email@mydomain.com

private getEmailAttribute(attributeList) {
    // Name: "email"...
    return ????;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`.find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) with [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) to get the object which has the `Name` of email. Then, once you have retrieved the object you can get the email by using the `.Value` property.

See example below:

```js
function getEmailAttribute(attributeList) {
  return attributeList.find(({Name}) => Name === "email").Value;
}

var attributeList = [{Name: 'email', Value: 'email@mydomain.com'},{Name: 'phone_number', Value: '+15555555555'}];
console.log(getEmailAttribute(attributeList));
```

As a side note. To declare a function in javascript, you do not use the `private` keyword. Instead, you can use the `function` keyword as I have above.

Answer (score 3):

You can get the email by using [`filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter), [`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [`shift()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/shift). This method is safe, it **will not throw** and will return `undefined` if it doesn't find the email object.

```js
const attributeList = [];

const attributeEmail = {
  Name : 'email',
  Value : 'email@mydomain.com'
};
const attributePhoneNumber = {
  Name : 'phone_number',
  Value : '+15555555555'
};
attributeList.push(attributeEmail);
attributeList.push(attributePhoneNumber);

function getEmailAttribute(attributes) {
    return attributes
      .filter(attr => attr.Name === 'email')
      .map(attr => attr.Value)
      .shift();
}

const email = getEmailAttribute(attributeList);
console.log(email);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`Array.prototype.find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) to get the `object` whose `Name = "email"` and then `return` its `Value`.

```js
var attributeList = [];

var attributeEmail = {
    Name : 'email',
    Value : 'email@mydomain.com'
};
var attributePhoneNumber = {
    Name : 'phone_number',
    Value : '+15555555555'
};
attributeList.push(attributeEmail);
attributeList.push(attributePhoneNumber);

function getEmailAttribute(list){
  let obj = list.find(item=> item.Name === "email")
  return obj && obj.Value;
}
let email = getEmailAttribute(attributeList);
console.log(email);
```